# Get property of object property  by string in C#

Tags: c#

How to access to property of property in object instance using string  ?
I would like automate changes i will made in form for example responding to object below:

```
class myObject{
   Vector3 position;
   public myObject(){
       this.position = new Vector3( 1d,2d,3d);
   }
};
```

Form have eg three `numericUpDown` called respectively `position_X`,`position_Y`,`position_Z`; 
Instead having three callbacks for events as:

```
private void positionX_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
    // this.model return myObject
    this.model().position.X = (double)  ((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;

  }
```

I would have one callback which can automatically set particular attribute in model from control name/tag

Below is javascript which describe purpose i want :)

```
position_Changed( sender ){
   var prop = sender.Tag.split('_'); ; // sender.Tag = 'position_X';      
   this.model[ prop[0] ] [ prop[1] ] = sender.Value;
}
```

Comment: If you are doing lots of this, you might want to look at FastMember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either reflection or expression trees to do that.

The simple reflection way (not very fast but versatile):

```
object model = this.model();
object position = model.GetType().GetProperty("position").GetValue(model);
position.GetType().GetProperty("X").SetValue(position, ((NumericUpDown)sender).Value);
```

**Note:** if `Vector3` is a struct you may not get the expected results (but that has to do with structs and boxing, not with the code per se).

Answer (score 0):

To complement the previous answer, which is essentially what you're looking for:

```
object model = this.model();
object position = model.GetType().GetProperty("position").GetGetMethod().Invoke(model, null);
var propName = (string) ((NumericUpDown)sender).Tag;
position.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetSetMethod().Invoke(model, new [] {((NumericUpDown)sender).Value});
```

That is, you could just use the `Tag` property of `Control` to specify to which property of your Vector3 object the `NumericUpDown` instance is "bound" to.